# std::pair class template has already been declared as a non-class template

Tags: c++, struct, class-template

I'm trying to declare two structs with the same structure as a below.

```
struct pair {
    unsigned int r1;
    unsigned int r2;
    unsigned int diff;
};

struct srm {
    struct pair *pairs;
    struct pair *ordered_pairs;
};
```

And it generate the error 'std::pair': class template has already been declared as a non-class template.

Please help me, why it occurs?
(I'm using vc12 (visual studio 2015))

Comment: Rename pair and don't use `using namespace std`.

Comment: [OT]: for `struct srm`, you may get rid of `struct` in `struct pair`.

Comment: Thanks guys. It works well